# How to enable PDF417 support for barcode scanning?

Tags: android, barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner

I followed the tutorial [here](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-Via-Intent) and it works like a charm. But I would like to enable `PDF417` support and I don't know how to do it.

Does anybody know how to enable `PDF417` in `zxing`?

I thought it can be on one of these lines(IntentIntegrator.java) by adding `PDF_417` but it seems it does not work.

`// supported barcode formats
  public static final Collection<String> PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES = list("UPC_A", "UPC_E", "EAN_8", "EAN_13", "RSS_14");`

`public static final Collection<String> ONE_D_CODE_TYPES =list("UPC_A", "UPC_E", "EAN_8", "EAN_13", "CODE_39", "CODE_93", "CODE_128","ITF", "RSS_14", "RSS_EXPANDED");`

Comment: possible duplicate of [ZXing PDF417 + ALL\_CODE\_TYPES](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567698/zxing-pdf417-all-code-types)

Answer (score 2):

Add to *initiateScan* parameter.

Quote:

Using ZXing (on Android), if you initiate a PDF417 barcode scan like this...

```
List<String> oDesiredFormats = Arrays.asList("PDF_417".split(","));
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
integrator.initiateScan(oDesiredFormats);
```

... and you initiate an "all codes" (except PDF417 and maybe a few others) barcode scan like this...

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
integrator.initiateScan();
```

From comment on [ZXing PDF417 + ALL_CODE_TYPES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567698/zxing-pdf417-all-code-types)

```
List<String> oDesiredFormats = Arrays.asList("UPC_A,UPC_E,EAN_13,EAN_8,RSS_14,RSS_EXPANDED,CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE‌​_128,ITF,CODABAR,QR_CODE,DATA_MATRIX,PDF_417".split(",")); 
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(Globals.g_oActivity); integrator.initiateScan(oDesiredFormats);
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3447790/mindmusic